# How to have a html link to another report in exported pdf of SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS reporting and I have a requirement described below:

I have Sales report created and each of the product has a link to go to another report which has product details. This works perfectly when deployed and viewed as html. But when the parent report is exported to pdf, the link to product does not work nor the link is highlighted.

Is there any configurations or setting to be done so I can view the product details from exported pdf report? Viewing the product details from the link can be using the browser. I just want to enable the html to next report on pdf.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are currently using a Go to report action to drillthrough to your product details report.  If that's correct, [drillthrough links are not supported in PDF rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255291.aspx), however you can switch your action to Go to URL and build a hyperlink to the report on your report server.  Your URL expression would then look something like the following:

```
="http://MyServer/ReportServer/?%2fMyFolder%2fProductDetailsReport&rs:Command=Render&MyParameter=" & Fields!ProductID.Value
```

Here are a couple links on building SSRS URLs:

- [MSDN URL Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx)
- [MSSQL Tips article on passing parameters in URLs](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-reporting-services/)